# Read a range of characters inside a text file with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm simply just trying to allow a person to choose their starting point and ending point and print the range. Anybody know how?

```
$file =  Get-Content C:\text.txt 
[int]$start = Read-Host "Where would you like to start in the file?"
[int]$end = Read-Host "How many characters do you want to see?"

Write-Host $file
```

Comment: I'm sure it is possible but how are you defining start point and end point? Also have you tried _anything_?

Comment: Asking the user where in the file he/she wants to start, then asking the user how many characters he/she would like to see. And no, I have not been able to find anything helpful on Google as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[int]$start = Read-Host "How many characters would you like to skip into the file?"
[int]$end = Read-Host "How many characters would you like to view?"

# Migh be [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII depending on how your text is encoded
$string = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString((Get-Content C:\getty.txt -encoding byte)[$start..($start + $end)])

Write-Host $string
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as Matt pointed it out, I doubt you tried anything with google, since [the answer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx)s are pretty easy to find ...

BUT ... I've been a lazy admin too so ... Here's the first step for your answer ...

```
 $a = gc u:\test.txt
 "$a".Substring(4, 6)
```

Comment: As much as I appreciate your answer, I really don't appreciate the way you went about answering it. Maybe be a little less critical and a little more helpful.